# Boost geometry/interprocess : find_or_construct stops responding

Tags: c++, memory-mapped-files, boost-interprocess, boost-geometry

I am storing an R-tree in a memory mapped file which is accessed by several processes. Each process is an instance of the same program, with different parameters. The tree is accessed in the following way:

```
std::cout << "Reading index at : " << idsFile.c_str() << std::endl;
bi::managed_mapped_file file_id(bi::open_or_create,idsFile.c_str(), bf::file_size(idsFile.c_str()));
allocator_m alloc_id(file_id.get_segment_manager());
std::cout << "Constructing tree ... " << std::endl;
rtree_m * id_ptr = file_id.find_or_construct<rtree_m>("rtree")(params_t(), indexable_m(), equal_to_m(), alloc_id);
std::cout << "The index contains " << id_ptr->size() <<  " entries." << std::endl;
```

(Please note that the processes make **no** modification to the tree, only queries.)

This fragment of code usually works fine, and has never failed me until now, when I was only running one process at a time. Now that I run 50 process simultaneously, it works fine for about 12 of them, and for the others, it remains stuck at the line

```
rtree_m * id_ptr = file_id.find_or_construct<rtree_m>("rtree")(params_t(), indexable_m(), equal_to_m(), alloc_id);
```

The output is simply

```
Reading index at : /path/to/file/rtree-ids.dat
Constructing tree ...
```

It doesn't crash, there is no exception, it just keeps trying to find_or_construct the tree and it lasts forever (well I killed it after 18 hours ; usually it's instantaneous). The state flag for the processes is R, not I nor S.

Worse : even after killing the 38 other processes, I have the same problem if I run a single process on the same memory-mapped file. it just doesn't respond anymore.  It looks as if the file had been "overused" and was now unreadable or something.

I couldn't find in the documentation anything about max number of processes or anything similar, so I turn to you guys for your wisdom.

Comment: Which Boost version are you using? In Boost 1.56 and before there was a bug in the rtree causing problems when Interprocess allocator was used.